# Building Parent Child object inside subscribe method

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5

I have an Angular component, that subscribes to an observable, returned by an Angular Service.

**Component:** 
**help.component.ts**

```
import { WikiService } from '../../../services/wiki.service';

import { WikiTree } from '../../../interfaces/WikiTree';

export class HelpComponent implements OnInit {

    wikiTree$: Observable<WikiTree>
    wikiChildTree$: Observable<WikiTree>

    public infoCards: Array<Object>;

    constructor(private wikiService: WikiService) {}

    ngOnInit() {
            this.wikiTree$ = this.wikiService.GetWikiHierarchy();
            this.wikiTree$.subscribe((data)=>{
            const newInfoCards = data.page.results.map(result => (
            {
              "image": "",
              "title": result.title,
              "titleLink": "/page/wiki/"+ result.id,
              "children": []  /*TODO: Populate this array with a Service call based on result.id*/
            }))
            this.infoCards = [...this.infoCards,...newInfoCards]
          },
          (err) => {
            console.log(err);
          }
       );
    }
```

The `wikiTree$` Observable has the following JSON, converted to TypeScript:

```
{
    "page": {
        "results": [
            {
                "id": "123456789",
                "type": "page",
                "status": "current",
                "title": "Start here",
                "extensions": {
                    "position": 0
                },
                "_links": {
                    "webui": "/display/MYSPACE/Start+here",
                    "edit": "/pages/resumedraft.action?draftId=123456789",
                    "tinyui": "/x/BQD2Mw",
                    "self": "https://wiki.abc.com/rest/api/content/123456789"
                },
                "_expandable": {
                    "container": "/rest/api/space/MYSPACE",
                    "metadata": "",
                    "operations": "",
                    "children": "/rest/api/content/123456789/child",
                    "restrictions": "/rest/api/content/123456789/restriction/byOperation",
                    "history": "/rest/api/content/123456789/history",
                    "ancestors": "",
                    "body": "",
                    "version": "",
                    "descendants": "/rest/api/content/123456789/descendant",
                    "space": "/rest/api/space/MYSPACE"
                }
            },
            {
                "id": "567890123",
                "type": "page",
                "status": "current",
                "title": "FAQ",
                "extensions": {
                    "position": 1
                },
                "_links": {
                    "webui": "/display/MYSPACE/FAQ",
                    "edit": "/pages/resumedraft.action?draftId=567890123",
                    "tinyui": "/x/HQD2Mw",
                    "self": "https://wiki.abc.com/rest/api/content/567890123"
                },
                "_expandable": {
                    "container": "/rest/api/space/MYSPACE",
                    "metadata": "",
                    "operations": "",
                    "children": "/rest/api/content/567890123/child",
                    "restrictions": "/rest/api/content/567890123/restriction/byOperation",
                    "history": "/rest/api/content/567890123/history",
                    "ancestors": "",
                    "body": "",
                    "version": "",
                    "descendants": "/rest/api/content/567890123/descendant",
                    "space": "/rest/api/space/MYSPACE"
                }
            }
        ],
        "start": 0,
        "limit": 25,
        "size": 2,
        "_links": {
            "self": "https://wiki.abc.com/rest/api/content/998877665/child/page"
        }
    },
    "_links": {
        "base": "https://wiki.abc.com",
        "context": "",
        "self": "https://wiki.abc.com/rest/api/content/998877665/child"
    },
    "_expandable": {
        "attachment": "/rest/api/content/998877665/child/attachment",
        "comment": "/rest/api/content/998877665/child/comment"
    }
}
```

**TypeScript: WikiTree.ts**

```
export interface WikiTree {
    page: Page;
    _links: Links;
    _expandable: Expandable;
  }
  export interface Page {
    results?: (ResultsEntity)[] | null;
    start: number;
    limit: number;
    size: number;
    _links: Links1;
  }
  export interface ResultsEntity {
    id: string;
    type: string;
    status: string;
    title: string;
    extensions: Extensions;
    _links: Links2;
    _expandable: Expandable1;
  }
  export interface Extensions {
    position: number;
  }
  export interface Links2 {
    webui: string;
    edit: string;
    tinyui: string;
    self: string;
  }
  export interface Expandable1 {
    container: string;
    metadata: string;
    operations: string;
    children: string;
    restrictions: string;
    history: string;
    ancestors: string;
    body: string;
    version: string;
    descendants: string;
    space: string;
  }
  export interface Links1 {
    self: string;
  }
  export interface Links {
    base: string;
    context: string;
    self: string;
  }
  export interface Expandable {
    attachment: string;
    comment: string;
  }
```

I would like to populate the `children` array with a call to the service based on it's parent `result.id`

Ex: The call would be to a function in Wiki Service, that returns an observable.

```
this.wikiChildTree$ = this.wikiService.GetWikiHierarchy(result.id);
```

From the data returned in the `wikiChildTree$` observable, I would like to create an array of `title` and `link` objects. So, the `infoCards` array of objects will reflect a JSON object like this:

```
[{
        "image": "",
        "title": "Start here",
        "titleLink": "/page/wiki/123456789",
        "children": [{
            "title": "Storm",
            "link": "/page/wiki/660431"
        },
        {
            "title": "Weather",
            "link": "/page/wiki/660432"
        }]
},
{
        "image": "",
        "title": "FAQ",
        "titleLink": "/page/wiki/567890123",
        "children": [{
            "title": "Cloud",
            "link": "/page/wiki/450433"
        },
        {
            "title": "Sunshine",
            "link": "/page/wiki/120432"
        }]
}
]
```

It's like making a parent child async call, to get child data.

I have read about forkjoin and mergemap, but not sure about the implementation here. How do I do that?

Comment: So you need to perform call for every **result** using **result.id**?

Comment: yes. that is correct

Comment: How many results do you usually have?

Comment: Will restrict it to 6 parents and 5 children in each parent through the API.

Comment: Ok, give me one second)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically you should be able to do that like:

```
ngOnInit() {
       this.wikiTree$ = this.wikiService.GetWikiHierarchy().pipe(
          switchMap(data => 
             forkJoin(data.page.results.map(result => this.wikiService.GetWikiHierarchy(result.id))).pipe(
                map(children => ({data, children}))
             )
          )
       ).subscribe(({data, children}) => {
            const newInfoCards = data.page.results.map((result, i) => (
            {
              "image": "",
              "title": result.title,
              "titleLink": "/page/wiki/"+ result.id,
              "children": children[i]
            }))
            this.infoCards = [...this.infoCards,...newInfoCards]
          },
          (err) => {
            console.log(err);
          }
       );
}
```

Explanation:

1. You load **this.wikiService.GetWikiHierarchy()**;
2. You load all **this.wikiService.GetWikiHierarchy(result.id)** for every **result** concurrently using **forkJoin.**
3. You map your loaded data from both places into object **{data, children}** where **data** - result from 1st call **children** - result from second **forkJoin (array of children or child[][])**.
4. After that you need to join **data.page.results** with **children (which is array of arrays)**.
   Hope that helps.

Comment: In the forkjoin call, I am seeing an error: Argument of type '(children: Observable<WikiTree[]>) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'UnaryFunction<Observable<WikiTree[]>, Observable<{}>>'.
  Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'Observable<{}>'. [2345]

Comment: Also, I don't see a way to create title and link objects in the children array in the fork join method.

Comment: Edited, forgot to put map() operator

Comment: The map() operator fixed that.. Now seeing this error on subscribe:  [ts] Parameter 'data' implicitly has an 'any' type, but a better type may be inferred from usage. [7044]
[ts] Argument of type '(data: any, children: any) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: { data: WikiTree; children: WikiTree[]; }) => void'. [2345]
(parameter) data: any

Comment: Sorry about that, but after that fix, I receive this error on this.wikiTree$.   [ts] Type 'Subscription' is missing the following properties from type 'Observable<WikiTree>': _isScalar, source, operator, lift, and 114 more. [2740]
(property) HelpComponent.wikiTree$: Observable<WikiTree>

Answer (score 0):

Added return data to Amir's answer to get rid of errors. The map function needed to return an observable of type wikiTree.

```
ngOnInit() {
       this.wikiTree$ = this.wikiService.GetWikiHierarchy().pipe(
          switchMap(data => 
             forkJoin(data.page.results.map(result => this.wikiService.GetWikiHierarchy(result.id))).pipe(
                map(children => ({data, children}))
             )
          )
       ).subscribe((data, children) => {
            const newInfoCards = data.page.results.map((result, i) => (
            {
              "image": "",
              "title": result.title,
              "titleLink": "/page/wiki/"+ result.id,
              "children": children[i]
            }))
            this.infoCards = [...this.infoCards,...newInfoCards]
            return data
          },
          (err) => {
            console.log(err);
          }
       );
}
```